# Guardar fecha en formato unix en Mysql

Tags: mysql, unix, timestamp

Necesito almacenar registros con campo en fecha y hora en formato Unix por defecto en una tabla de mysql, es posible hacer eso? se podrá crear una tabla con ese campo por defecto?

Comment: Quizá si explicaras la finalidad para la que quieres tener esa columna en tu tabla se podría clarificar un poco la respuesta adecuada. Una solución viable sería crear en tu tabla una columna cuyo tipo de dato sea `TIMESTAMP` y cuyo valor por defecto sea `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. Este tipo de columnas se usa por ejemplo para marcar el momento preciso en que se creó una fila. En el `CREATE TABLE`  la columna sería más o menos así: `created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Answer (score 3):

Se puede guardar, pero aclarando lo siguiente

1. El tipo de dato que arrojará al estar en formato UNIX es de tipo INT
2. Se debe usar la función `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`

EJEMPLO

Esta es la tabla donde guardaré la información incluida la fecha en formato UNIX

```
CREATE TABLE data(
 name VARCHAR(20),
 fecha INT
);
```

Al momento de realizar el insert, el tipo de dato para que funcione debe ser por ejemplo `"1997-10-04 22:23:00"`

Al momento de realizar la inserción debe quedar de este modo

```
INSERT INTO data
VALUES
("alfred", UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()));
```

Al momento de consultar la fecha, esta debe mostrarse como a continuación de visualzia

```
SELECT * FROM data;

name    fecha
alfred  1535763496
```

Si después de eso necesitas recuperar la fecha pero pasarla del formato UNIX a una formato como el que mas arriba se menciona, debes hacer esto

```
SELECT name, FROM_UNIXTIME(fecha) FROM data;
```

Y el resultado que deberías visualizar es el siguiente

```
name    FROM_UNIXTIME(fecha)
alfred  2018-09-01 02:02:39
```

Aquí te dejo información de fuentes oficiales sobre las 2 funciones usadas

1.- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime

2.- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp

> Te dejo en este [enlace](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=94a7c9c624a924f2f703d6de04de1d30) el ejemplo funcional de todo lo que te
>   explico mas arriba